# iOS: How to use a RGBA image and have UIImageView accept it as partially transparent? (Getting black for transparent pixels)

Tags: ios

I'm loading a partially transparent/translucent RGBA PNG into an UIImage, and setting that as the image as a UIImageView. Unfortunately it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: do not use a translucent image. instead use a opaque image with 100% transparent pixels where required and set tht imageview.alpha = (transparency value) between 0 and 1 where 0 is 100% transparent.

Comment: I have no choice, as the images are coming from another person. They have alpha values ranging from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need a view behind the image, that is what shows through the transparent pixels.

Comment: You're adding a view to the subviews collection of a UIImageView?

Comment: No, that was a typo. I'm setting the image in a UIImageView.